# eclipse maven project deploying error

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, tomcat, deployment

i am trying to deploy my maven project in eclipse using goal **clean tomcat7:deploy**

in tomcat-users.xml:

```
<user username="milma" password="milma" roles="manager-gui" />
```

in pom xml:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
<configuration>
    <url>http://localhost:8080/company</url>
    <server>TomcatServer</server>
    <path>/company</path>
</configuration>
 </plugin>
```

in m2/settings.xml:

```
                      <server>
                      <id>TomcatServer</id>
                      <username>company</username>
                      <password>company</password>
                      </server>
                      </servers>
                      </settings>
```

why i getting this error?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) on project milma: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection reset by peer: socket write error -> [Help 1]
```

does any one can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your URL for uploading is worng. it must be: `http://localhost:8080/manager/text`

```
<configuration>
    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
    <server>TomcatServer</server>
    <path>/company</path>
</configuration>
```

Because the URL is the URL of the tomcat Manager servlet, not the URL where your application should be called.

Comment: after changing url same error is repeating what can i do? please help

Comment: @pjishnu your tomcat is running on port 8080? can you call the URL by Hand?

Comment: yes running in 8080. do i need to change the port number? by hand 404 error has occurred

Comment: @pjishnu no. can you call the URL in a browser?

Comment: So it Looks like the Manager is not installed. can you check it?

Comment: how can i check it

Comment: @pjishnu look in the directors <tomcat_home>/webapp. There must be a Directory Manager if it is installed

Comment: @pjishnu that is strange. what is happend, if you only call `http://localhost:8080/`?